# using interpolation in .env files

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, config, dotenv

I'm trying to use a `.env` file in a node app and `dotenv` NPM module to read it, but use some variables and interpolation.
what works in a standard bash file doesn't seem to run within a .env config file though. e.g., given:

```
APP_NAME=tixy
MONGODB_URI="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/${APP_NAME}"
```

will come out directly in code

```
const mongoUri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
```

as `"mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/${APP_NAME}"`

is there a way to get a `.env` config to run?
perhaps I could 'source' it as the app starts up and use `export` for all the vars, but that seems kludgey...

Comment: Why not just compose it inside your code? Like `MONGODB_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/` and then in your code `const mongoUri = process.env.MONGODB_URI + process.env.APP_NAME`?

Comment: good point but i wanted to keep in the dotenv as I have some other bash files referencing the same configs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`dotenv` won't expand environment variables, but you could use [`dotenv-expand`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-expand) in addition to `dotenv` to get this behavior:

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv')
var dotenvExpand = require('dotenv-expand')
 
var myEnv = dotenv.config()
dotenvExpand.expand(myEnv)

// Should be OK now.
const mongoUri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
```

Comment: neato i didn't know about that.